# How can I set up an alias, function or variable as a shortcut to "2>&1 | tee build.log"?

Tags: bash, shell

As the subject line says, I'd like a quicker way to type "2>&1 | tee build.log"

Or even better, I'd like a shortcut which did expanded to 2>&1 | tee $1.$2.log" where $1 and $2 are taken from the current line.

I've tried a few different things and here are the problems I found

1. Aliases seem to apply to first words (or first word after another alias) only. So I'm pretty sure they can't help.
2. A function can work - e.g. "log ant compile", but it has the undesirable side effect of breaking tab expansion as it moves the first arg to the second, etc.
3. A variable can sort of work e.g LOG='2>&1 | tee build.log', except it must be expanded manually with an esc-ctrl-E or the 2>&1 gets passed as a parameter.

Does anybody know a better way to do this?

Thanks- 
    Carter

Comment: 2 is the way to go. You can fix tab expansion by writing additional tab expansion rules for your function or script.

Answer (score 3):

May I suggest a 4th option, a readline macro?

Add the following to your `~/.inputrc` file (creating it if necessary):

```
"\C-x\C-l": " 2>&1 | tee build.log"
```

New shells will automatically process this file; you can try to re-read the file in your current shell by pressing Control-x Control-r ( I forget if that's configured by default or not).

Now, any time you press Control-x Control-l, the text " 2>&1 | tee build.log" will be inserted at the cursor.

UPDATE:

```
"\C-x\C-l": "\eb\eb2>&1 | tee \ef\C-d.\ef"
```

will allow you to type

```
build log
```

followed by Control-x Control-l to convert it to

```
2>&1 | tee build.log
```

Comment: What a great solution. I just set up a readline macro. It gives me nearly exactly what I want without sacrificing tab expansion. Thanks.

Comment: +1 Interesting solution; would've never thought of it (but am definitely trying it for other things now =P)!